# Bucle infinito de mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedure

He de sacar un procedimiento almacenado, para simplificar fracciones (dividir por el mismo número numerador y denominador). Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el script se queda ejecutándose un buen rato y se corta la conexión de MySQL.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
delimiter //
create procedure simpfrac(IN denom int, IN numerad int)
    begin
        declare contador int;
        set contador = 0;
        -- Creamos un bucle en el cual usamos un contador para ir simplificando las fracciones
        incremento: loop
            set contador = contador+1;
            if (denom % contador = 0) and  (contador < denom) and (numerad % contador = 0) and (contador < numerad)
                then
                    begin
                        set denom = denom / contador;
                        set numerad = numerad / contador;
                    end;
            else if (numerad = denom)
                then
                    begin
                        select 'El resultado es 1, no hace falta simplificar';
                        leave incremento;
                end;
            else if (denom < numerad) and (contador = denom)
                then
                    leave incremento;
            else if (denom > numerad) and (contador = numerad)
                then
                    leave incremento;
            end if;
            end if;
            end if;
            end if;
        end loop incremento;
        end;// 
        delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución**

Debes corregir el bloque siguiente:

```
        if (denom % contador = 0) and  (contador < denom) and (numerad % contador = 0) and (contador < numerad)
            then
                begin
                    set denom = denom / contador;
                    set numerad = numerad / contador;
                end;
```

... y reemplazarlo con (nota los 2 cambios: `contador > 1` y `set contador = 0;`):

```
        if contador > 1 and (denom % contador = 0) and  (contador < denom) and (numerad % contador = 0) and (contador < numerad)
            then
                begin
                    set denom = denom / contador;
                    set numerad = numerad / contador;
                    set contador = 0;
                end;
```

**Explicación**

En efecto, tienes un bucle infinito. La razón es que si entras en la condición donde simplificas la fracción:

```
begin
    set denom = denom / contador;
    set numerad = numerad / contador;
end;
```

... necesitas resetear la variable `contador` antes de seguir iterando en el bucle. De lo contrario, es posible que al reducir `denom` y `numerad`, que ambas variables ahora tengan valores mas pequeños que `contador`. Y si esto llega a suceder, quiere decir que las 2 otras condiciones `contador = denom` y `contador = numerad` nunca llegarán a ser ciertas a medida que `contador` sigue creciendo.

Y de todas maneras, lógicamente, una vez que hayas reducido una vez la fracción, necesitas recomenzar la búsqueda de simplificaciones con `contador` a cero:

```
begin
    set denom = denom / contador;
    set numerad = numerad / contador;
    set contador = 0;
end;
```

Pero eso no es todo. Hay otra corrección que necesitas. De lo contrario aun tendrás un bucle infinito.

Cuando `contador = 1`, la condición:

```
if (denom % contador = 0) and  (contador < denom) and (numerad % contador = 0) and (contador < numerad)
```

... a menudo evaluará a `true`, porque el modulo 1 (`n % 1`) de cualquier numero siempre es igual a cero.  Pero no tiene sentido simplificar la fracción si `contador = 1`, porque dividir cualquier numero por `1` no simplifica nada.

De modo que la segunda corrección necesaria es de agregar una condición para que evites tratar de simplificar la fracción cuando `contador = 1`:

```
if contador > 1 and (denom % contador = 0) and  (contador < denom) and (numerad % contador = 0) and (contador < numerad)
```

En realidad, pudiera sugerirte muchas mejoras en el diseño de tu algoritmo, pero me limito a identificar el problema básico que tienes con tu bucle infinito.

Comment: Gracias, me han dicho que con el máximo común divisor se saca, pero prefiero darme cuenta de mis fallos